# SwitchPreference's graphic does not change

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
SwitchPreference switchPreference = new SwitchPreference(preferenceScreen.getContext());
switchPreference.setKey(sensor.getName());
switchPreference.setTitle(sensor.getName());
switchPreference.setChecked(true);
```

If I check for the status of the switch with

```
switchPreference.isChecked()
```

It returns the correct boolean value as true. However, the switch's graphic is always at the state where it was set on the previous run.

The switches are dynamically created in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); //almost empty
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
    PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = new PreferenceCategory(preferenceScreen.getContext());
    preferenceCategory.setTitle("Sensor List");
    preferenceScreen.addPreference(preferenceCategory);

    for (TrackingData sensor : SensorService.data)
    {
        SwitchPreference switchPreference = new SwitchPreference(preferenceScreen.getContext());
        switchPreference.setKey(sensor.getName());
        switchPreference.setTitle(sensor.getName());
        switchPreference.setChecked(true);
        Log.d(TAG_SENSOR,switchPreference.getKey() + "'s status is " + switchPreference.isChecked());
        preferenceCategory.addPreference(switchPreference);
    }
}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{


    SwitchPreference preference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(key);
    boolean value = preference.isChecked();
    if (value)
    {
        //start tracking this sensor
        Log.d(TAG_SENSOR, key + " tracking enabled");
    }
    else
    {
        //stop tracking this sensor
        Log.d(TAG_SENSOR, key + "tracking disabled");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the code in your onSharedPreferenceChanged()?

Comment: it's almost an empty method which I am going to implement something when the graphic shows the switches' states correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found out the fix was to set SwitchPreference's persistent value to false